# SwiftUI CollectionView

Tags: swift, swiftui

First of all, i'm sorry for my bad english. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMr2b.png)I just started with SwiftUI and ran into a problem. I could not do as in the design, I will use each box as a button.

Comment: you need the same design as the image?

Comment: Yes i need this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I hope this answer your question, and each box is a button.

```
struct GurkanEsenView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("önceki")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .overlay(
                     RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                     .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                    )
                    
                
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Kahve")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                        
                    
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Cay")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                        
                    
                }
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Ozel")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                        
                    
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Ada")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                        
                    
                }
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Uyum")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                        
                    
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("H")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7239437103, green: 0.2440972626, blue: 0.4727140069, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8527825475, green: 0.821311295, blue: 0.8959596753, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3)
                        )
                        
                    
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
        .padding()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    
}
}
```

[image: Result]